# How to resolve service worker error in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker

I am getting a service worker error while running my react app.
Can you please help me why it's getting the error. Screenshot link is given below,

[Servier worker error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SrXp.png)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers/rootReducer';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import config from './config/index'
import App from './App';
import './index.scss'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const store = createStore(rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({}))
  )
);

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple mistake =)

Look at this line:

```
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
```

and then look here:

```
serviceWorker();
```

On the first line of code you're importing the whole module into your file's scope as 'serviceWorker'. On the second line you're trying to call that module. But you cannot call a module, it's not allowed. It's also what the error message says right at the top of your screenshot.

I think what you actually should be doing is something like this:

```
import { register } from './serviceWorker';
...
...
register();
```

or something similar. It might also be `registerServiceWorker` or something like that. Look at the `./serviceWorker.js` file and find out.

One thing to note: I would seriously consider ***_not using_*** Service Workers in your project until you know exactly how they work, what they are etc. It is SUPER EASY to cause a lot of problems by using Service Workers without really knowing them.